# How does the SmtpClient function without a host name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have an ASP.NET application running on Windows Server 2003 and as part of its functionality it sends emails to users in response to user registrations, password resets and the like.  It runs inside a local area network (inside a state government firewall, in fact).  Here is some typical code:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(FromEmail);
message.To.Add(ToEmail);
message.Subject = Subject;
message.Body = FormattedMessageText;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

Note that it is invoking the SmtpClient constructor without specifying a hostname!  And the Send works just fine.  I'm trying to understand how this might be working without a specified hostname (other applications on the same webserver use a specific hostname).  This one doesn't use one, yet still works!  Except for one particular function, which doesn't work in all cases, but in one particular case it always returns "Unable to connect to the remote server", which I've experienced in the past as a failure to specify a hostname.

The odd thing is that there is a mailSettings node in the web.config.  It is apparently the default value as it was created at the time the application was developed:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25" userName="" password="" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Is there anything specified in your web.config (or application) for smtp? It could be using the default relay server but hard to tell.

Comment: Check also the machine.config of the machine where the application is hosted

Comment: @Sam, I've added the mailSettings in web.config to the question.  There's nothing interesting concerning Smtp or mailSettings in machine.config

Comment: According to your edit I could say that it's using the smtp default relay server. This could cause an issue if the Sys admins change smtp server settings and require all users to provide user credentials. Therefore it's recommended to specify host name, user name and password in your config settings.

Answer (score 2):

If not specified in a web.config as in @WPalombini answer, then if the machine has the **Microsoft SMTP Service** installed (or is an Exchange Server), then the message is being written to a file and thus gets queued up for delivery by the Microsoft SMTP Service (or Exchange Server). If the Microsoft SMTP Service is configured to point to a valid SMTP server in your network, then your messages will be delivered. Otherwise they would just queue up in the mail folder on the machine (which by default is usually c:\inetpub\mailroot\queue\ ).

Answer (score 1):

You can check your web.config file under configuration section.
Example:

```
    <mailSettings>
    <smtp_1 from="user@domain.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp" />
    </smtp_1>
  </mailSettings>
```

Also, the transform part:

```
    <mailSettings  xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <smtp_1 from="user@domain.com">
      <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.domain.com" port="587" userName="user@domain.com" password="mypassword" />
    </smtp_1>
  </mailSettings>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <smtp from="user@domain.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.domain.com" port="587" userName="user@domain.com" password="mypassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: I added the mailSettings to the question a few minutes ago.